# Add Numbers from two different forms

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I want to obtain Numbers from different forms, add them up and display the output in a different form.

For example, There are two forms: Form 1 and Form 2. The information I need is located in Form 1. So I get the numbers from Form 1, add them up and display the result in Form 2.

I am not sure how to proceed here.
Please advice.

Comment: You have not supplied anything like enough information for a sensible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the text box where you want to output the answer, go to properties > Go to data>Constrol source>click on "..." and type the following code:

Forms!Form_3!Text_3.Value=(Val(Forms!Form_1!Text_1.Value)) / (Val(Forms!Form_2!Text_2.Value))

Comment: No, that will not work the way you have it and it is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I cannot tell you unless you can say what is the real world problem that you wish to solve. The above has quotes, which will stop it working, and unnecessary functions and properties.

Comment: I have editted the above comment. That is how I have it in my text box property.

Comment: I want to get a number from form_1 and multiply it with a number in Form_2. Next, I want the output to be displayed in Form_3, text_3.

Comment: Why? Why would you want to confuse a user with three forms?

Comment: That is what I want/ What the user want